# How to conditionally override a sass variable?

Tags: sass

I'm working on a RTL sass solution, trying keep RTL changes next to their LTR counterparts (rather than a separate stylesheet). I have some functions that depend on a $dir variable. So if it is set to 'ltr' the LTR rules are used. If set to 'rtl', the RTL rules are used.

So my code is:

```
$dir: ltr;
@function if-ltr($if, $else: null) {
    @if $dir != rtl {
        @return $if;
    }
    @else {
        @return $else;
    }
}
@function if-rtl($if, $else:null) {
    @return (if-ltr($else, $if);
}
@mixin if-ltr {
    @if $dir != rtl {
        @content;
    }
}
@mixin if-rtl {
    @if $dir == rtl {
        @content;
    }
}
html[dir='rtl'] {
    $dir: rtl;
}

p {
    color: black;
}

@include if-rtl {
    p {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Logically I would think that in the case of the html tag's dir attribute being set to 'rtl', the variable $dir would be set to 'rtl' but this does not happen. I can override this by setting $dir: rtl !global but this changes it for the default ltr case as well.

So it seems that a variable in sass can only be set to one value? (It would not negate the 'variable' moniker as it would still be useful for changing the same value in multiple places at once.) Or is there a way around this? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm just curious if you've looked into using something like [gulp-css-flipper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-flipper). It will generate a separate CSS file (which you said you're hoping to avoid) but you won't have to write much CSS for the RTL version of the site.

Comment: Hey @Katharine , did you find any solution?